# Locust load test: having an issue on user timings spawned by locust

Tags: python, load-testing, locust

I have been working on Locust lately, I wanted to know if we can manage the user timings for each user or a set of users maybe. for example, how can I replicate a user being on for a certain amount of time and then killing the user.
I am not sure how we can handle this.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html):

In addition to the `task_set` attribute, one usually wants to declare the `min_wait` and `max_wait` attributes. These are the minimum and maximum time respectively, in milliseconds, that a simulated user will wait between executing each task. `min_wait` and `max_wait` default to 1000, and therefore a locust will always wait 1 second between each task if `min_wait` and `max_wait` are not declared.

With the following locustfile, each user would wait between 5 and 15 seconds between tasks:

```
from locust import Locust, TaskSet, task

class MyTaskSet(TaskSet):
    @task
    def my_task(self):
        print "executing my_task"

class MyLocust(Locust):
    task_set = MyTaskSet
    min_wait = 5000
    max_wait = 15000
```

The `min_wait` and `max_wait` attributes can also be overridden in a `TaskSet` class.

Comment: My question is, can you control how long a particular user instance can be on and kill it when I want to?
Say maybe like,